# Pure virtual functions not defined in Singleton DLL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, interface, singleton

I'm trying to build a DLL which will manage various configuration options for my project as a Singleton.

I followed the method proposed [here in the chosen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333935/using-a-singleton-across-dll-boundary), as shown below:

*IBuildConfiguration.h*

```
#if defined(BUILD_CONFIGURATION_LIBRARY_EXPORT)
#   define BUILD_CONFIGURATION_API   __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define BUILD_CONFIGURATION_API   __declspec(dllimport)
#endif  // BUILD_CONFIGURATION_LIBRARY_EXPORT

class IBuildConfiguration
{
    public:
        virtual int foo(void) = 0; 
};

BUILD_CONFIGURATION_API IBuildConfiguration& Instance(void);
```

*BuildConfiguration.h*

```
class BuildConfiguration : public IBuildConfiguration
{
    public:

        BuildConfiguration();
        ~BuildConfiguration();


        virtual int foo(void);
};
```

***Edit: Forgot to include implementation of `Instance()`***

*BuildConfiguration.cpp*

```
int BuildConfiguration::foo(void)
{
    return 1; //just a silly example
}

IBuildConfiguration& Instance(void)
{
    static BuildConfiguration instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Now, in Visual C++ 6, I added to my project a dependency on this new DLL and I included the *IBuildConfiguration* header in my source as such:

*SystemCtrl.cpp*

```
#include "../../BuildConfiguration/IBuildConfiguration.h"

IBuildConfiguration buildConfig = Instance();
```

**My DLL builds successfully, however the project that uses it does not.**

Unfortunately, this results in the following error:

```
int __thiscall IBuildConfiguration::foo(void)' : pure virtual function was not defined
```

copying the DLL and LIB files into the project doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: I think the Instance method is trying to create an instance of your base class. which cannot be done for the reason reported.

Comment: @Rob See my comment below; my bad, I didn't provide the implementation of `Instance()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `IBuildConfiguration` did not have a pure virtual function, this would still not work as you're expecting:

```
IBuildConfiguration buildConfig = Instance();
```

This basically says "copy-construct an instance of `IBuildConfiguration` from the return value of `Instance()`". The derived class info is lost. This is slicing. You need your variable to be a reference:

```
IBuildConfiguration& buildConfig = Instance();
```

Comment: I was just about to update my answer with this :) congrats. that should do it.

Comment: It does solve the problem, however, now I'm getting another error: `unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class IBuildConfiguration & __cdecl Instance(void)" `

Comment: Then you didn't properly link to the `.lib` file for your DLL. I don't remember exactly how, but it is in linker options. (It has been at least 8 years since I used VC++ 6.)

Comment: @DarkFalcon perfect, I added `/libpath:"..\BuildConfiguration\Debug\\" ` to the project options

Answer (score 2):

make sure your Instance method looks like this

```
 IBuildConfiguration& Instance()
 {
    // Creates instance of derived class all is good.
    static BuildConfiguration inst;
    return inst;
 }
```

and not:

```
 IBuildConfiguration& Instance()
 {
    // Tries to create instance of base class.. Not possible as it
    // has pure virtual functions.
    static IBuildConfiguration inst;
    return inst;
 }
```

Dark Falcon is right, you need to store the return from the Instance() method in a reference to the base class or it will try to create a new instance of the base class by calling the base class copy constructor same problem :).

Comment: Whoops, that was my fault, I forgot to include the implementation of 'Instance()' in my original answer